# Move all files in one FTP directory to another on same server using PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I want to move all files located in 'Directory A' to 'Directory B' on the same FTP Server.

I have searched this site and found a similar question but the solution did not work for me and I am unable to comment as my reputation is less than 50.

The below code shows what I have tried so far;

```
$Source = "ftp://ftp3.example.com/Jaz/In/" 
$user = 'username' 
$pass = 'password'

$credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)

$ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::create($Source)
$ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::Rename   
$ftprequest.RenameTo = "ftp://ftp3.example.com/Jaz/Backup"
```

Note:

> - 'Directory A' = ftp://ftp3.example.com/Jaz/In
> - 'Directory B' = ftp://ftp3.example.com/Jaz/Backup
> - All files to be moved are .txt format
> - Full permissions have been granted to all files & folders on FTP

Can someone please help with a solution, your knowledge is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no support for batch or recursive FTP operations (like moving all files from directory to another) in PowerShell or .NET.

If you want to use a pure PowerShell, you have to move the files one by one.

```
$source = "ftp://ftp.example.com/source/path/" 
$dest = "/dest/path/"

$credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")

Write-Host "Listing files..."

$listRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($source)
$listRequest.Credentials = $credentials
$listRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::ListDirectory

$files = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$listResponse = $listRequest.GetResponse()
$listStream = $listResponse.GetResponseStream()
$listReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($listStream)
while (!$listReader.EndOfStream)
{
    $file = $listReader.ReadLine()
    $files.Add($file) | Out-Null
}
$listReader.Dispose()
$listStream.Dispose()
$listResponse.Dispose()

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    Write-Host "Renaming $file..."
    $renameRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($source + $file)
    $renameRequest.Credentials = $credentials
    $renameRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::Rename
    $renameRequest.RenameTo = $dest + $file
    $renameRequest.GetResponse().Dispose()
}
```

The above code will move all entries in the directory (files or subfolders).

Other problems in your code (fixed in mine):

- You never use `$credentials`
- `RenameTo` is a path only, not an URL.

---

The code would be much simpler with a better FTP client.

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell), it's as easy as:

```
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
    HostName = "ftp.example.com"
    UserName = "username"
    Password = "password"
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

$source = "/source/path" 
$dest = "/dest/path"

$files = $session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(
             $source, $Null, [WinSCP.EnumerationOptions]::MatchDirectories)
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    Write-Host "Renaming $file..."
    $session.MoveFile(
        $file.FullName, [WinSCP.RemotePath]::Combine($dest, $file.Name))
}
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: @MartinPrikryl thank you for WinSCP and also for this excellent answer. This was very useful and extremely easy to modify for my requirement of recursive moving! If anyone else needs to move all files from various subdirectories, one must only swap out `::MatchDirectories` with `::AllDirectories`.